# AMP version of page won't load on mobile (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, mobile, amp-html

1) AMP is enabled for posts on the site.

2) AMP is enabled for this particular post:
https://www.writermag.com/get-published/freelance-writing/freelancing-profits/

3) AMP version of page exists here:
https://www.writermag.com/get-published/freelance-writing/freelancing-profits/amp

Yet when I access the page from a mobile device (iphone X to be exact), it won't load the AMP version but instead loads the desktop version.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

WordPress version = 4.9.9
AMP version = 0.7.2

Comment: When you access your website on desktop or mobile Its always show non amp page.  amp page show on google search on mobile devices. You can search your page in google and come from there than its show amp page.

Comment: I tried accessing that page via google SERPS and same result. No amp page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid amp page. Try to solve that first.

Comment: How can you tell that?